# Firebase firestore timestamp to Formatted Date

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, redux-firestore

I am working on a firebase project and for displaying time regarding and entity, what i got is the timestamp. I am working on a react native project. How to convert the received timestamp to properly formatted date. 
This is the timestamp:

[image]

I have this time available in `this.props.time` , and so i tried `this.props.time.toDate()` but what i got was an error.
`Invariant Violation:Objects are not valid as a React child(found: Tue Nov 26 2019 11:51:58 GMT+05:30(Indian Standard Time))`

Comment: I guess you could just convert it something like `new Date(this.props.time.seconds * 1000)`

Comment: I thinks it conveted properly but error is on displaying it. Can you provide code how you displayed it ?

Comment: @KishanBharda  fixed it ! I need to convert it to string. What i done is : new Date(
                    this.props.time.seconds * 1000 +
                      this.props.time.nanoseconds / 1000,
                  ).toLocaleDateString()

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) with `new Date(time.seconds * 1000 + time.nanoseconds/1000000)` then manipulate it the way you want.

Comment: It worked after i did it like this: new Date(
                    this.props.time.seconds * 1000 +
                      this.props.time.nanoseconds / 1000,
                  ).toLocaleDateString()

Answer (score 1):

If you retrieve your data from the document, you can do this:

```
// time.toDate()
convertDate(doc.data().time.toDate())

const convertDate = (date) => {
    // whatever formatting you want to do can be done here
    var d = date.toString()
    return d.substr(0, 21);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://momentjs.com/ to display

{moment(yourTimestamp.toDate()).format(
****format is inside the link above
 )}

Answer (score 1):

Correct:
`new Date(time.seconds * 1000 + time.nanoseconds/1000000)`

NOT correct:
`new Date(time.seconds * 1000 + time.nanoseconds/1000)`

Because, 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For firestore v9 you can simply do like this.

You can use toDate() function along with toDateString() to display the date part alone.

```
const date = dateCreated.toDate().toDateString()
//Example: Friday Nov 27 2017
```

Suppose you want only the time part, then use the toLocaleTimeString()

```
const time = dateCreated.toDate().toLocaleTimeString('en-US')
//Example: 01:10:18 AM, the locale part 'en-US' is optional
```

And let's say you need to extract month and day from the date.

You simply do this:

```
const date = new Date(Date.now());
date.toLocaleString('en-US', {month: 'short'}); // {month:'long'}
Expected Output: "Jan"
```